# Send e-mail by SendGrid

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

I have the following structure to send email with `SendGrid`:

```
import mail from '@sendgrid/mail';

function send(email_data) {
  mail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

  const message = {
    to: email_data.to,
    from: email_data.from,
    subject: email_data.subject,
    text: email_data.text,
  };

  return mail.send(message);
}

export default send;
```

In my controller I call the method as follows:

```
const email_data = {
  to: 'myemail@hotmail.com',
  from: 'some_other_email@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Deposito realizado',
  text: 'Foi feito um deposito na sua conta ...',
};

mail.send(email_data);
```

But the following error is displayed to me:

`(node:7963) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: _sendgrid2.default.send is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Probably `'@sendgrid/mail'` file is not working properly. Your error message: `.default.send is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

To call `mail.send` you have to import mail in the controller

Try this: Controller

```
 import mail from '@sendgrid/mail';
 const email_data = {
   to: 'myemail@hotmail.com',
   from: 'some_other_email@gmail.com',
   subject: 'Deposito realizado',
   text: 'Foi feito um deposito na sua conta ...',
 };

 mail.send(email_data);
```

Send Grid

```
import mail from '@sendgrid/mail';

function send(email_data) {
  mail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

const message = {
   to: email_data.to,
   from: email_data.from,
   subject: email_data.subject,
   text: email_data.text,
};

 return mail.send(message);
}

 export default send;
```